# Mongodb How to add index on Regex query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using the following query to fetch data

```
db.objects.find({
            _type_uid: "test",
            _environment: "b1ca19f54230b7af20",
            locale: "en-us",
            locales: {
                $in: ["en-us"]
            },
            scheduled: false,
            $and: [{
                $or: [{
                    display_name: {
                        $regex: "\b(key agency)",
                        $options: "gim"
                    }
                }, {
                    $and: [{
                        display_name: {
                            $regex: "\b(key|agency)",
                            $options: "gim"
                        }
                    }, {
                        content: {
                            $regex: "\b(key|agency)",
                            $options: "gim"
                        }
                    }]
                }, {
                    content: {
                        $regex: "\b(key agency)",
                        $options: "gim"
                    }
                }]
            }]
        }).
        sort( {
            "exp_metadata.time": -1
        }).limit(20)
```

But ht query taking time to complete so need to add an index here so what is the best index here? display_name,content and exp_metadata.time is text field

Comment: Your current use of regex on the `display_name` field can't really be indexed.  Are you intending to run the regex against anywhere in the display name?

Comment: is possible to include display_name and content in regex or what is the best regex here?

Comment: Can you explain the exact search logic with examples?